# why does interface return null instead of true/false

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i have been searching for an answer on the internet for a while and cant really find a good explanation so sorry if this is a repeat question. i dont exactly understand how interfaces work. i am trying to use an interface to return a true bool condition. any help would be appreciated. thanks in advance. here is what i think is all relevant code:

```
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using UnityEngine;
 
 public interface IDamageable
 {
     BaseStats Stats { get; }
     List<GameObject> HitTargets { get; }
     GameObject Target { get; set; }
 
     void TakeDamage(float amount);
     
 } 
 
 using UnityEngine;
 using UnityEngine.UI;
 
 [System.Serializable]
 public class BaseStats
 {
 [SerializeField]
     private SphereCollider detectionObject;
 [SerializeField]
 private GameConstants.OBJECT_TYPE objectType;
 [SerializeField]
 private GameConstants.OBJECT_ATTACKABLE objectAttackable;

 public GameConstants.OBJECT_ATTACKABLE ObjectAttackable
 {
     get { return objectAttackable; }
 }
 public GameConstants.OBJECT_TYPE ObjectType
 {
     get { return objectType; }
 }
 public SphereCollider DetectionObject
 {
     get { return detectionObject; }
 }
}

using UnityEngine;

public static class GameConstants
{
public enum OBJECT_TYPE
 {
     GROUND,
     FLYING
 }
 
 public enum OBJECT_ATTACKABLE
 {
     GROUND,
     FLYING,
     BOTH
 }

 public enum UNIT_RANGE
 {
     MELEE,
     RANGE
 }
}

using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Photon.Pun;

public class Units : MonoBehaviour, IDamageable, IPunObservable
{
[SerializeField]
 private BaseStats stats;
 
 [SerializeField]
 private List<GameObject> hitTargets;

 public List<GameObject> HitTargets
 {
     get { return hitTargets; }
 }
 public BaseStats Stats
 {
     get { return stats; }
 }
public void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
 {
     if(!other.transform.CompareTag(gameObject.tag))
     {
         Component damageable = other.transform.gameObject.GetComponent(typeof(IDamageable));
         if(damageable)
         {
             if(!hitTargets.Contains(damageable.gameObject))
             {
                 hitTargets.Add(damageable.gameObject);

             }
         }
     }
 }
}
```

damageable is returning a null condition. i know this through debugging. i have all objects set to "ground" type and attackable in the inspector. am i not using the interface correctly? am i not assigning something? i thought as long as the interface was inherited it would work. thanks.

Comment: Why do you think `other.transform.gameObject` contains a `IDamagable` component?

Comment: I have never programmed in Unity, but i am nevertheless capable of reading the documentation for [GetComponent](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponent.html). It says right there: "_Returns the component of Type type **if the game object has one attached, null if it doesn't**._" So, basically: Do you have an IDamaged instance (i.e. some object of a type that implements `IDamaged`) attached to whatever is `other.transform.gameObject`? Apparently not...

Comment: What exactly is supposed to return `true` or `false`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using interfaces correctly. It seems like the GameObject with the trigger Collider just doesn't have any components that implement IDamageable (such as Units) attached to it.

You can add this logging to the beginning of your OnTriggerEnter event function and check that the `other` object is the one you are assuming it to be, and that it has the components that you are assuming it to have. You can pause the game and click on the message in the Console to highlight the `other` object in the Hierarchy.

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    Debug.Log(other.name + " contains components: " + string.Join(", ", other.GetComponents<Component>().Select(c => c.GetType().Name).ToArray()), other);
```

Answer (score -1):

Let me know if my understanding is wrong but from what I see-

1. You have an interface "IDamageable" which determines if an object can be damaged or not
2. In Class UNITS, you have inherited "IDamageable" interface
3. In UNITS, after collision, you're trying to see if the object that you collided with has "IDamageable" interface or not.

Component damageable would return NULL for the following reasons -

1. Assigned to WRONG object. "IDamageable" should be assigned to objects which are colliding with "UNITS" class. So if I have a gun/sword, "IDamageable" script should be attached to things which gun/sword can damage and not on the sword itself.
2. Check if collisions are working properly.
3. Check if Rigidbodies are attached to objects
4. Check "isTrigger", if enabled or disabled, Rigidbodies needs to be modified accordingly.

Now for some extra information -
INTERFACE!
They are generic classes with only declarations and no implementations.

Suppose you have to design a shop system where you need to sell cars. There are 1000 different types of companies.

Basic (not recommended) method -

```
Class Toyota 
{
    string name;
    int price;
}
Class Volvo
{
    string name;
    int price;
}
Class Maruti
{
    string name;
    int price;
}
```

Here, you are defying the basic programming rule- DO NOT REPEAT YOURSELF (DRY principle)

Now, same code implemented with INFERFACE -

```
Interface CarProperties
{
    string name;
    int price;
}
Class Toyota : CarProperties
{}
Class Volvo : CarProperties
{}
Class Maruti : CarProperties
{}
```

Now for both the code types, all I need to do is Toyota.VariableName.name to access the STRING NAME variable.
Since every car, no matter the company, make year, etc SOME VARIABLES WOULD EXIST AS GENERIC.

These generic variables & functions can be stored as an extra INTERFACE class and inherited to all the rest of the classes.

Comment: FYI: Interfaces are NOT generic classes. Saying otherwise is bollocks :-) Generic classes are generic classes.  Interfaces are NOT even classes. Classes are classes. Doing `typeof(ISomeInterface).IsClass` on an interface type will of course yield false. Interfaces can be generic, but not every interface is generic. For example, the IDamageable this question is about is NOT a generic interface. Also, beginning with C# 8, interfaces can have default method implementations. There is work done to bring this to Mono (which Unity uses, iirc) as well, but i don't know the exact milestones...

Comment: Finally, variables are not generic. This doesn't make sense, because only types and methods can be generic, not variables. Variables can be of a type defined by a (generic) type parameter, but that doesn't make the variable generic. Variables can also be of a type that is generic, but's the type that's generic, not the variable.

Comment: Thank you for your response. All objects have the units script attached to them so they should all inherit iDamageable. Collisions are working because debugging shows that onTriggerEnter is being called. All objects also have rigidbodys attached and is trigger is checked. I could add that I am using the photon rigidbody view although it automatically attaches a regular rigidbody to the object. I will go back and verify all these mentioned possibilities.

Comment: For future reference it must be a unity flagging issue with photon. i rearranged the items in the inspector and it seems to be working. thanks to everyone.